# Wordpress и меню

Tags: wordpress, меню

Вывожу верхнее меню на сайте таким образом (header.php, взято из шаблона):

```
<?php $args = array( // опции для вывода верхнего меню, чтобы они работали, меню должно быть создано в админке
        'theme_location' => 'top', // идентификатор меню, определен в register_nav_menus() в function.php
        'container'=> 'nav', // обертка списка
        'menu_class' => 'top-menu', // класс для ul
        'menu_id' => 'top-nav', // id для ul
        );
        wp_nav_menu($args); // выводим верхнее меню
    ?>
```

Хочу так же вывести меню в сайдбаре. И тут возникает вопрос, как могу указать какие страницы выводить в верхнем меню, а какие в сайдаре?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно [зарегистрировать](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu) новое меню в `functions.php`:

```
register_nav_menu('my-new-menu', 'Мое дополнительное меню в сайдбаре');
```

Таким образом вы объявляете вордпрессу, что в теме есть меню с идентификатором `my-new-menu`. Jстается только вывести его где-нибудь:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'my-new-menu'));
```

По умолчанию такое меню будет просто брать и выводить все страницы. Однако в административной части, во внешнем виде -> меню (если не ошибаюсь), можно составить свое произвольное меню и присвоить этому идентификатору.